# Is there a possibility to identify the port of a WMS?

Tags: wms

Because I always get an error message when I try to connect with a sepcific WMS.
From my testings I can exclude port 80.

Comment: Port is a part of an URL and service provider must give you a working URL to GetCapabilities. If GetMap and GetFeatureInfo are using other URLs you can read them from GetCapabilites.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The specific WMS I am talking about is the following:
http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1
I have tried to implement it in ArcGIS and QGIS without success. However, the provider told me that the WMS works fine (including pictures of evidence). So, I think the firewall blocks a specific port needed to run the WMS and that is the reason for my original question.

Comment: http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1&request=getcapabilities works for me

Comment: can you show us the error message?

Comment: Error message in Firefox:
_<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1"><ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
Unknown service requested.
  </ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>_

Comment: Error message in ArcGIS for http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1
_One or more layers failed to draw:
Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg:   WMS service exceptions:-Service Error Code:InvalidFormat
Service Error Description: Parameter 'exceptions' contains unacceptable value.
-Service Error Code:InvalidFormat_

In ArcGIS the layers of the WMS are identified correctly but when I try to visualize the error message above is visualized.

Comment: Try to use the full and valid GetCapabilities string http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS

Comment: The 1.3.0 version also works [http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&]

Answer (score 2):

Both of the errors you list are errors from the WMS so there is no issue talking to it, the first:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
  <ServiceException code="InvalidFormat"> Unknown service requested. </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

just means you forgot to mention the service you wanted so make sure you have `service=wms` in your url.

I found that http://service.salzburg.gv.at/arcgis/services/Strassengraph_WMS_Land_Salzburg/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1&request=getcapabilities&service=wms works fine.

Once you have a capabilities document back it tells you or your client everything it needs to know to make the service work.